# How to repeat content infinitely on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/VwKzbQa) I'm trying to repeat the contents of both columns infinitely when you scroll. They're supposed to scroll in different directions (I know it looks a bit strange), and just keep looping through the content.

I think I need to figure out when the the div reaches the bottom of the window and then repeat the content? But I'm not sure how to repeat content..

Any help is appreciated.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window)
      .scroll(function () {
        $(".right").css(
          "transform",
          "translate3d(0," + $(this).scrollTop() * 2 + "px, 0)"
        );
      })
      .scroll();
  });
```

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display:flex;
}

.col-6 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 left">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 right">
        <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
      <img class="full-width" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What should be when the scroll bar reaches its limit?

Comment: I need it to loop. So scrolling up and down would just loop through the content over and over again.

Comment: I understood your requirement, but it's not clear what should happen if the scrollbar reaches the very bottom ?! Should the scrollbar rise to the top again?

Comment: Sorry. This - https://www.craig-reynolds.com/all-work --  is similar to what I'm talking about. See how it just loops through? I'm not sure how they're achieving it

Comment: This is definitely a plugin's job.

Comment: Yeah thought so, just can’t find one that does the job

Comment: what cms or framework do you use?

Comment: using wordpress